# BaseHTTPServer, only receive once my variables post

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, simplehttpserver, basehttpserver

Hi I have this code for my variables post, I want this always listening and receiving post requests, works fine but after receiving the first varibles follows the script running but no longer get the post varibles.

Only works well once, then have to restart the python script.

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import urlparse
import os

HOST_NAME = ''
PORT_NUMBER=8000

postVars = ''

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(s):
        global postVars
        s.send_response(200)
        s.end_headers()
        varLen = int(s.headers['Content-Length'])
        postVars = s.rfile.read(varLen)
        #print postVars

server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)

try:
    httpd.handle_request()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

#print postVars

qs = dict( (k, v if len(v)>1 else v[0] )
           for k, v in urlparse.parse_qs(postVars).iteritems() )
#print qs

pass = qs['pass']
domain = qs['domain']
user = qs['user']

os.system("./createuser.sh %s %s %s" % (pass,user,domain))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

thank for all

Comment: How do you send request?

Comment: Looks good, so I also suspect it might have something to do with the sending. I am using the exactly same technique here, you could look for inspiration. https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets/src/bf2c3affa5528c6e96bfcc96b0caf4b0c9a9ec27/cryptoassets/core/backend/blockiowebhook.py?at=master#cl-79 - add some debug logging maybe?

Comment: 'the script running but no longer get the post varibles.' How do you say you are not getting POST vars?. It's running forever. How do you check?

Comment: I am check, follow code:
**#ps aux | grep server.py **
my print process is running

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the end of your script. You take some name to vars, but get another one.

change this

```
pase = qs['pass']
dominio = qs['domain']
usuario = qs['user']

os.system("./createuser.sh %s %s %s" % (pass,user,domain))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

for this

```
passwd = qs['pass']
domain = qs['domain']
username = qs['user']

os.system("./createuser.sh %s %s %s" % (passwd, username, domain))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Just typo :-)

Comment: edit my code, but still the error still thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

If you call `serve_forever` you can't do anything in this thread. Do tasks in another thread or loop and call `handle_request`.

```
HOST_NAME = ''
PORT_NUMBER=8000
postVars = ''
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(s):
        global postVars
        s.send_response(200)
        s.end_headers()
        varLen = int(s.headers['Content-Length'])
        postVars = s.rfile.read(varLen)
        #print postVars

server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)

while True:
    try:
        httpd.handle_request()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    qs = dict( (k, v if len(v)>1 else v[0] )
           for k, v in urlparse.parse_qs(postVars).iteritems() )
    pass = qs['pass']
    domain = qs['domain']
    user = qs['user']

    os.system("./createuser.sh %s %s %s" % (pass,user,domain))
```